# How can I monitor the space of std::vector when I debug with visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, monitor

When I debug with visual studio 2022.if I want to know how much space be used by a vector or a deque or a priority-queue,what can I do?

Comment: For a `std::vector` the debugger will show `[capacity]` which is the number of items currently allocated.

Comment: no, it does not